# run : rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono

Tags: image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi , i want to start image processing with ROS, i think i should work wih `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono` but when i run this command i have a window  like this i dont know how work with this command :

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono
or 
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

so please some one help and guide me to work with this and first step for image processing ?
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222372/run-:-rosrun-image_view-image_view-image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono/) by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-12-11**:
Are image topics being published?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-12-11**:
http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport
Go through the tutorials for this package

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
hi 130s , im beginner at ROS, so could you please explain me more about topics that should be published i mean how could i publish?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
hi 2ROS0 , i did every thing for `image_transport` but i had a window without any thing like the picture is in my question what should i do?

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
What type of camera are you using? Webcam or some else?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
hi , its my webcam for my laptop .

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
please help me

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
Actually, the problem is you are not getting the image from webcam, just using image_view can't show you image. You have to get the image on image:=**/Image/topic**. If you were using usb webcam it would have been much easier but for integrated webcam i am not able to find any package for indigo.

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
But i have just written my own package for integrated laptop webcam. I will try to upload and give you link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just download package from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6dU4Fr-GLrYWtSYXppVFpEaHc/view?usp=sharing)  extract it in your `work_space/src` run `catkin_make` and then `rosrun webcam_pub webcam_pub`.

Then you can use `image_view image_view image:=/webcam/image_raw`

---

Originally posted by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) with karma: 96 on 2015-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
@fatima ! had this solution worked for you?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
hi Ameer , thanks for help, but when i run rosrun webcam_pub webcam_pub i have this error : [ERROR] [1449937759.389801015]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
what should i do in your idea?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
it works Ameer , very thank you , i don know how to thanks, GOD bless you , now i could start image processing if you could guide me for that to start too please tell me .again thank you so much

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
I think you were missing `roscore`. What do you want to know about image processing? Do you know openCV?

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-12**:
yes thats right roscore was missing, now its working, i know opencv a little but think may be i could work with image_proc but it looks like opencv is the only way rights?

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
Image_proc is only used for image rectification. For general purpose application u should use OpenCV. I suggest to start with this tutorial. Although written for visual studio for windows but you can easily use it in linux. It will give u general intro of openCV.

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2015-12-12**:
https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_2.4.11_Windows_Installation_Guide

**Comment by [Marouane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25895/marouane/) on 2016-02-09**:
Hello,
I am also new to ROS and I am facing the same problem, can you please send me the link again, because the one in your comment above is not working anymore

**Comment by [Ameer Hamza Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24969/ameer-hamza-khan/) on 2016-02-10**:
@Marouane  Here is the link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6L50j9T2roKNTBPelpJUnJKbjg/view?usp=sharing
To change the webcam, you need to change the `cv::VideoCapture cap(0)` line in main function.

**Comment by [Marouane](https://answers.ros.org/users/25895/marouane/) on 2016-02-11**:
@Ameer thank you very much for your help, I was able to better understand how everything is working.